# Copy file line by line

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, eof

I have a problem with a loop, what i want to do is copy a file, line by line.
I used this code but it in the output file write one more bracket and one line.

```
void copyStringNewFile(ifstream& inData,ofstream& outData)
{
string x = "";

while (inData)
{
    getline(inData, x);
    outData << x << '\n';
}
}
```

Probably i can remove the line:

```
string x = "";
```

In the while conditions I've tried a few solution:

```
while (!inData.eof())    // Works similar to while (inData)

while (inData >> x)      // Delete a lot of lines
```

Thank you so much, and if you can explain where eof can be useful (because in loops it seems useless).

Comment: Thank you to all i used the:
`outData << inData.rdbuf();`
I have one last question, why if i put the getline function in while condition, it will be executed and not just evaluated.
Thanks again :D!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of getline(). When it fails, no copy should be made.
Btw, you are also depending on a final '\n' in the source file, otherwise you'll have trouble copying the last line.

Here's a form that monitors successful reads properly:

```
void copyStringNewFile(ifstream& inData, ofstream& outData)
{
    char ch;
    while (inData >> ch)
    {
        outData << ch;
    }
}
```

Or if you're ready to use a more advanced form:

```
void copyStringNewFile(ifstream& inData, ofstream& outData)
{
    outData << inData.rdbuf();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
while (getline(inData, x)) {
    outData << x << '\n';
}
```

You are seeing the last line duplicated because you are testing the stream and THEN trying to read from it; the status of the stream as "EOF" is only set after trying - and failing - to read.